# Nginx proxy_cache_key $request_body is ignored for large request body

Tags: http, nginx, reverse-proxy, multipartform-data, cache-control

I use nginx as a reverse proxy and I would like it to cache POST requests. My back-end is correctly configured to return appropriate cache-control headers for POST requests. In nginx I have configured:

```
proxy_cache_methods POST;
proxy_cache_key "$request_method$request_uri$request_body";
```

This works great for small HTTP POST requests. However I started noticing that for large requests (e.g. file uploads) it seems like the `$request_body` is ignored in the `proxy_cache_key`. When a form containing a file upload is submitted twice with completely different data, nginx will return the cached result.

What could cause this? How can I configure nginx to use the `$request_body` (or a hash of `$request_body`) in the `proxy_cache_key` even for large POST requests?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So it turns out that when `$content_length > client_body_buffer_size`,
then the request body is written to a file and the variable `$request_body == ""`.

See also http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2013-September/040442.html

Comment: In my access log, I was writing the contents of $request_body and was seeing only "-" (dash/hyphen) instead of the contents. I assumed there was a max length to either the access log or the $request_body variable, but couldn't find any reference to that. Your answer hit the nail on the head. Thank you for this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the $request_body within the proxy_cache_key, you may more simply use $content_length.
Of course, it comes with its own limitation, but if you know which query you will receive, it can be also a very interesting workaround.

```
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$content_length";
```

You may alternatively use $request_body as well to keep the desired behavior for smaller request payload:

```
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$request_body$content_length";
```