# Nginx proxy_buffer_size is not enought for cache key

Tags: caching, nginx

I need to cache POST response in my work. So I have the next location:

```
location /api {
    client_max_body_size 1m;
    client_body_buffer_size 1m;
    proxy_buffers 16 128k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_cache api;
    proxy_cache_methods POST;
    proxy_cache_key "$request_uri|$request_body";
    add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
}
```

My nginx version is 1.8.0

When I am sending POST request with large body I get this message in nginx error.log:

```
proxy_buffer_size 4096 is not enough for cache key, it should be increased to at least 129024
```

Nginx documentation has the next description:

> **proxy_buffer_size** 
>   Sets the size of the buffer used for reading the first part of the response received from the proxied server. ***This part usually contains a small response header.*** By default, the buffer size is equal to one memory page. This is either 4K or 8K, depending on a platform. It can be made smaller, however.

What is the relation between *proxy_buffer_size* and *cache key*? How can I cache response in this case?

Comment: POST are not usually cached, is this a ASP POSTBACK you're talking about or an html form trying to post to your backend such as php? Try to delete all those tweaks (first 4 lines), restart and try again.

Comment: @peixotorms Not, it is not POSTBACK. I have REST API service that I POST json of ids and want to get back json of names. Howerver if I delete first 4 lines it can't cache because request body very large and  `client_body_buffer_size` is small by default.

Answer (score 4):

First I would like to recommend using GET instead of POST, so you can use `proxy_cache_key "$request_method$host$request_uri";` and therefore have no need to adjust your buffers for this to work.

Also while increasing the buffers might work, it adds a lot of overhead because you're including the whole request body in your cache key. Similar to REDIS, Memcache and others, a cache key should be unique and short (and you are making it too big).

If you must use POST you need to tune it to a few Megabytes, like this:

```
location /api {
    client_max_body_size 12m;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 255;
    proxy_buffers 8 2m;
    proxy_buffer_size 12m;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 12m;
    client_body_buffer_size 12m;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_cache api;
    proxy_cache_methods POST;
    proxy_cache_key "$request_uri|$request_body";
    add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
}
```

Having a big buffer won't use up all your memory, but according to http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2013-September/040447.html *"it can be used as a DoS vector if an attacker is allowed to open many connections but you can't afford them all to allocate client_body_buffer_size buffer"*.

Also it seems that acording to this answer: [Nginx proxy_cache_key $request_body is ingored for large request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795701/nginx-proxy-cache-key-request-body-is-ingored-for-large-request-body) 
when `$content_length > client_body_buffer_size`, then the request body is written to a file and the variable `$request_body == ""`... so this is another thing to consider, as your `$request_body` might be empty and you will get colisions on your cache.

Having said that, I would strongly recommend for you to change from POST to GET, add a COOKIE or find some other way to identify your requests / users.
If you're having a large amount of big POST requests, it won't scale very well with many requests.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know about POST cache problem, but I really need to cache POST request in my case (see: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/03/limitations-of-the-get-method-in-http/). Never mind about DoS attacks, it is used like internal service. Yes Nginx have a problem when `$request_body` is ignored for large request body, so I set `client_max_body_size ` and `client_body_buffer_size` for solve this problem. I want to know how `proxy_buffer_size` depends on request body size if I use it as proxy_cache_key and why I am getting errors.

Comment: Your proxy_buffer_size should be at least as big as your POST data size. Did you try my answer configuration? How big is your POST anyway?

Comment: Yes, your configuration works great as well as my configuration if I increase `proxy_buffer_size`. So why I should increase that? Nginx documentation tells me that: ` Sets the size of the buffer used for reading the first part of the response received from the proxied server. This part usually contains a small response header. `. My POST request body size usually is 1 MB and the response body size usually is 2 MB.

Comment: note, that the `proxy_buffer_size` may not be as large as the product of the two values in `proxy_buffers`, see https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/363#issue-211499381

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `$request_body` in the cache key, you should set `proxy_buffer_size` to a value greater than the sum of 
`client_body_buffer_size` and the resoponse header size.

See: http://nginx.2469901.n2.nabble.com/upstream-sent-too-big-header-while-reading-response-header-from-upstream-td7588354.html